# Docusign: HTTPS required for Connect listener communication error

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm trying to use the Docusign API for an application that I'm running locally and I see the following error:

```
"message":"Uncaught Error when executing a Single
Cause: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while 
requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: 

'{"errorCode":"HTTPS_REQUIRED_FOR_CONNECT_LISTENER",
  "message":"HTTPS required for Connect listener communication."}'

Description: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while 
requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: 

'{"errorCode":"HTTPS_REQUIRED_FOR_CONNECT_LISTENER",
"message":"HTTPS required for Connect listener communication."}
```

I am behind a company proxy but I have been able to use the API in the past and create envelopes without an issue so I'm not sure how to address this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answers to your questions. MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change is discussed in the [Jan release notes](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/release-notes/rn_esignature_2021_01_en.pdf).

Connect can only be used with `https` listeners (customers' servers).

And note that the server must use a certificate that chains to a root cert in the Microsoft standard root cert list. (Self-signed certs won't work.) You can use a free cert from LetsEncrypt or a $15 cert from a reputable CA.

I'm sorry that this update caught you by surprise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Larry! Is it true that only Connect (aka the webhook) is affected by this? I have been able to make other types of DocuSign requests without seeing that error.

Comment: https must be used for calling any DocuSign API. Https is not required (but is recommended) for the redirect urls used with embedded signing views and oauth redirects.

Comment: can I bypass that when testing locally?

Comment: @JChao, sorry, no. HTTPS is required in all situations.

Answer (score -1):

Getting error now, it was working fine before:
Fatal error: Uncaught DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:35:"HTTPS_REQUIRED_FOR_CONNECT_LISTENER";s:7:"message";s:50:"HTTPS required for Connect listener communication.";}