# DocuSign Error HTTPS_REQUIRED_FOR_CONNECT_LISTENER

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

I am getting error like below on DocuSign rest, it was working fine before:

Fatal error: Uncaught DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:35:"HTTPS_REQUIRED_FOR_CONNECT_LISTENER";s:7:"message";s:50:"HTTPS required for Connect listener communication.";}

TIA

Comment: Make sure you are using HTTPS and that the cert's root is commonly used, probably something that [Microsoft trusts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/release-notes). All paid certs should be fine, as well as Let's Encrypt

Comment: Duplicate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945582/64904 for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change is discussed in the [Jan release notes](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/release-notes/rn_esignature_2021_01_en.pdf).

Connect can only be used with `https` listeners (customers' servers). This applies to both developer and production accounts.

And note that the server must use a certificate that chains to a root cert in the Microsoft standard root cert list. (Self-signed certs won't work.) You can use a free cert from LetsEncrypt or a $15 cert from a reputable CA.

I'm sorry that this update caught you by surprise.

Answer (score 2):

There seems some weird behaviour around this since the recent update.
Please try adding :443 to the URL, this resolved the issue in testing.